# How can I call method on custom List<T> from a property?

Tags: c#, vb.net, properties, generic-list

So I'm currently working on rewriting a VB.NET application I've been working on to C# (for a refreshser) and I've run into a bit of a snag that I can't seem to figure out. I am trying to cycle through an objects properties and get all properties that are of Type CustomList<T> and run the Save method on each.

VB.NET Code for CustomList

```
Friend Class CustomList(Of T)
    Inherits List(Of T)

    Private ReadOnly Property FileName As String
        Get
            Return GetType(T).ToString + ".json"
        End Get
    End Property
    Private ReadOnly Property Campaign As Campaign
    Private ReadOnly Property FilePath As String
        Get
            Return Source.SourcePath + FileName
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Sub New(source As Source)
        _Source= source
        If IO.File.Exists(FilePath) Then Me.AddRange(JSON_Functions.LoadJSONObject(Of CustomList(Of T))(FilePath))
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(objList As List(Of T))
        Me.AddRange(objList)
    End Sub

    Public Sub Save()
        JSON_Functions.SaveJsonObject(FilePath, Me)
    End Sub
End Class
```

C# Code for Custom List

```
public class CustomList<T> : List<T>
    {
        private static string FileName { get { return typeof(T).Name + ".json"; } }
        private Source Source { get; set; }
        private static string FilePath { get { return Source.Path + FileName; } }

        public CustomList(Source source)
        {
            this.Source = source;
            if (File.Exists(FilePath))
                this.AddRange(GlobalElements.JSON_Functions.LoadJsonObject<CustomList<T>>(FilePath));
        }

        public CustomList(List<T> objList) { this.AddRange(objList); }
        public void Save() { GlobalElements.JSON_Functions.SaveJsonObject(FilePath, this); }
     }
```

I am trying to call the Save command on each property of CustomList but have hit nothing but dead ends on this. In VB.NET I was able to do this in a relatively straightforward method, but in C# I have found nothing that is the equivalent.

My end goal is being able to save Object1List, Object2List, Object3List, etc. via a loop instead of having to call each properties Save method individually.

VB.NET Code for Save methods (this handles any generic list, but I am still able to call a method without it being apart of VB.NETS Object definition)

```
    Public ReadOnly Property Object1List As CustomList(Of Object1)
    Public ReadOnly Property Object2List As CustomList(Of Object2)
    Public ReadOnly Property Object3List As CustomList(Of Object3)

    //other code stuffs

    Public Sub SaveCampaign()
        For Each p As PropertyInfo In Me.GetType.GetProperties
            If GetType(IList).IsAssignableFrom(p.PropertyType) AndAlso p.PropertyType.IsGenericType Then p.GetValue(Me).Save()
        Next
    End Sub
```

C# Code for Save methods

```
        public CustomList<Object1> Object1List { get; private set; }
        public CustomList<Object2> Object2List { get; private set; }
        public CustomList<Object3> Object3List { get; private set; }

       //Other Code Stuff

        public void SaveSource()
        {
            foreach (PropertyInfo p in this.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                if (typeof(IList).IsAssignableFrom(p.PropertyType) && p.PropertyType.IsGenericTypeDefinition)
                   p.GetValue(this).Save();
            }
        }
```

This returns error on `p.GetValue(this).Save();`:

```
    'object' does not contain a definition for 'Save' and no accessible extension method 'Save' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

The biggest reason I want to accomplish this is that I might have 10+ CustomList<T> and don't want to list them every time.

If anyone could offer some advice, I would greatly appreciate it!!!

Comment: Not quite understand your problem, why you have 3 properties (Object1List, Object2List, Object3List) and try to loop through properties? why not have 1 property List<CustomList<Object1>> and loop through this List?

Comment: @Alex-TinLe The issue is that Object1, Object2, and Object3 are all different types. The CustomList<T> is used to so that it can save a list of any object types that I give it. If I was only working with one specific type within the list, I wouldn't need to use a generic type for CustomList.

Comment: Check out my answer, you can have 1 common Interface. Then use a List<IMyCustomList>.

Comment: @Alex-TinLe That did get it working. Thank you very much!! The root of my goal for doing this is to just eliminate copy&paste code and have something just says, "Save all of these if you have them".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the option is

```
public interface IMyCustomList
{
    void Save();
}

public class CustomList<T> : List<T>, IMyCustomList
{ .... }
```

Then cast your property value to the interface

```
var propValue = p.GetValue(this);
if (propValue != null && propValue is IMyCustomList myList)
    myList.Save();
```

But still, I don't think it's good to loop through the properties like that.

Comment: Why do you not think it's not good? In my mind, it makes sense to use reflection to when nested objects need to be saved.

Comment: Normally, we decide "what" to save by using a contract (in my code, it's an interface). That's why I will go for only 1 List<IMyCustomList> property. In your code, you simply reading all properties and try to match them with some conditions. Let's assume, if one of your teammate add another property which match with your conditions, but he is NOT aware of that saving method. Now, you need to always keep an eye on those.

Comment: That's fair. This is just a personal project I'm working on so no one else has hands on it currently. There might be grounds for refactoring it once I delve deeper into the project, but for now this suites my needs greatly. Thank you again.